# Show that $(\mathbf{a}·\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{b}·\mathbf{b})-(\mathbf{a}·\mathbf{b})^2=(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})·(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})$?

Tags: proof-writing, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

I need to prove that, for two linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^3$,

$$(\mathbf{a} · \mathbf{a}) (\mathbf{b} · \mathbf{b}) - (\mathbf{a} · \mathbf{b})(\mathbf{a} · \mathbf{b}) = (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})·(\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b})$$

Could someone give me a demonstration of this identity? Or a hint to prove it?

Comment: Use coordinates, perhaps?

Comment: I would like, rather than checking it by substituting the coordinates, to prove it from some other existing property.

Comment: Note that it's also true when $a$ and $b$ are not linearly independent. It's a special case of [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Comment: For some reference, sometimes $(A\times B)\cdot (C\times D)$ is called the *quadruple product*.

Comment: It is known as the [Binet-Cauchy identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $(A\times B)\cdot (A\times B) = |A\times B|^2 = |A|^2|B|^2\sin^2\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them. Now we have $\sin^2\theta = 1-\cos^2\theta$, and I will remind you that $A\cdot B = |A||B|\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 4):

The left hand side is the [determinant of the Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant) of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$:
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf a & \mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b \\
\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf a & \mathbf b\cdot\mathbf b\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In general, the determinant of a Gramian matrix is the square of the $n$-dimensional volume of a parallelotope, in this case the square of the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$.

The right hand side is $\|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b\|^2$, where $\|\mathbf a\times\mathbf b\|$ also is the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$, hence both sides are equal.

Answer (score 2):

For a unit vector $u$, $|u\cdot v|$ is the length of the projection of $v$ onto $u$ (which is also the distance of $v$ from the plane perpendicular to $u$) and $|u\times v|$ is the length of the projection of $v$ onto the plane perpendicular to $u$ ($u\times v$ is the projection of $v$ onto the plane rotated by $\frac\pi2=90^{\large\circ}$ counter-clockwise).

[image]

The Pythagorean Theorem says
$$
|u\cdot v|^2+|u\times v|^2=|v|^2\tag1
$$
Due to the linearity of "$\cdot$" and "$\times$", we can remove the restriction on $u$ by making the equation homogeneous; here, substitute $u\mapsto\frac{u}{|u|}$ (which changes nothing if $|u|=1$) and multiply by $|u|^2$:
$$
|u\cdot v|^2+|u\times v|^2=|u|^2|v|^2\tag2
$$